# Doobie: create constant table with values

Tags: postgresql, scala, doobie

Postgres allows creation of constant tables for use in queries with this syntax:

```
WITH names (id, name) AS (VALUES (1, 'ABC'), (2, 'BCD')) 
  SELECT id FROM names
```

or the inlined version:

```
SELECT id FROM (VALUES (1, 'ABC'), (2, 'BCD')) AS t (id, name);
```

assuming I have an instance of a `Meta[T]` for `T` a case class, is there a way of writing a generic function that takes `List[T]` and creates me a table of `T` values.